# How to convert content within a div into a series of variables?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a rough bit of code I borrowed from another site that has served me well in one regard, but now I'm having some trouble.

I have a file that can be saved with a series of variables... Variable X is 17, and Variable Y is 5. You hit the save button and you download a txt file with the content being "17 05". That part I definitely have down-pat and do not need help with.

However, once I have this file with the "17 05" inside of it, I upload it to the HTML and it spits out the content into a DIV. Boom, "17 05" right in my HTML, cool as hell. Except... How do I get this completely new HTML to sort out "17" and "05" as Variables X and Y like it was in the aforementioned HTML?

```
function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {

var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
if (!files.length) {
    alert('Please select a file!');
    return;
}

var file = files[0];
var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;
var reader = new FileReader();

// If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
    }
};

var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
}

document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
        var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('datastart');
        var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('dataend');
        var strxs = evt.target.getAttribute('ds-str');
        var strxe = evt.target.getAttribute('de-str');
        $('#flodump-str #start').text(strxs);
        $('#flodump-str #end').text(strxe);
        var readStr = $('#flodump-str').text();
        $('#devtestdump span').text(readStr);
        readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
}, false);
```

With this current code that I barely understand, it takes the byte number from the HTML and reads it from a certain amount (startByte) to another amount (endByte) and dumps it all in one location.

My problem, as I'm trying to do is... well, get it to dump in multiple places! If I can just get "17" and "05" into separate spans, that's childs play to finagle them as variables. However, they're both in one div, without any differentiating spans or id tags, its just one DIV with number salad as its content... unless there's some method to reach into a DIV using the same character count / byte number method and say "the first two characters are Variable X, the next two characters are Variable Y."

Either that, or there's a way to get this whole readBlob business to have multiple outputs for each specified byte area?

Can anyone help me with this? Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I should note that I left some of my half-hearted attempts to fix the problem myself within the code. I tried to export the specified byte fields as variables, only to find out that instead of outputting the content, it outputted the actual byte fields, like "35 and 37" for reading the position within the text file, as opposed to the actual content at the 35 and 37 position.

EDIT2: I should also note that "17" and "05" is just an example for brevity's sake. I have about forty of these two-digit variables in my actual text file.

Comment: It might help if you used the jquery selectors and click functions

Comment: @Binvention Well, it's one click. After the text file is loaded, you click the button and it shows them on screen (which I have) and then converts the content into variables (which I need help with)

Comment: I know I was saying that click function is using the JavaScript document selector if you use the jquery .click function you will have the much more usable jquery this object.

Comment: And you could also look into the jquery Ajax functions to handle your file request. I believe it returns json objects which are simpler to parse then blobs

Comment: @Binvention That sounds lovely, but I unfortunately have no idea how to do that.

Comment: is the files your accessing on your server correct? and an easy place to go if you don't know how to use jquery is api.jquery.com it has everything in there. i can help some but id need to understand the situation better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If I can just get "17" and "05" into separate spans, that's childs
>   play to finagle them as variables. However, they're both in one div,
>   without any differentiating spans or id tags, its just one DIV with
>   number salad as its content... unless there's some method to reach
>   into a DIV using the same character count / byte number method and say
>   "the first two characters are Variable X, the next two characters are
>   Variable Y."

Try defining `X` , `Y` as property names of an object , using `String.prototype.match()` with `RegExp` `/\d+/g` to return one or more digit characters followed by digit characters , `Object.keys()` to retrieve property names of created object , `Array.prototype.forEach()` to set properties `X` , `Y` to matches found in `div` . If expected result is for `X` and `Y` to be number objects , can cast string returned by `.match()` to number utilizing `Number(res[i])` , where `res` is array returned by `.match()` , `i` is index of item in array iterated within `.forEach()`

```js
var obj = {X:void 0, Y:void 0};
var res = document.querySelector("div").textContent.match(/\d+/g);
Object.keys(obj).forEach(function(val, i) {
  obj[val] = res[i]
})
console.log(obj)
```

```html
<div>17 05</div>
```

Comment: I don't understand a lot of what you just said. Does this code register "17" and "05" as two different variables I can manipulate with the var function?

Comment: @R.Little _"Does this code register "17" and "05" as two different variables I can manipulate"_ Essentially, yes ; though `X` , `Y` were assigned as properties of a generic object. To access `X` or `Y` can use `obj.X // "17"` or `obj.Y // "05"` . To set `X` , `Y` globally can adjust `obj[val] = res[i]` to `window[val] = res[i]`